# time out connecting to wi fi network

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

My wifi connection works normally in most networks, but I have a problem connecting to a speficic network.

I can connect to this network with other devices, using the same WPA password. Other people can connect just fine.

I get the following in `/var/log/syslog` when trying to connect to this network using network manager:

`May  7 15:24:22 box kernel: [320056.009993] wlan0: direct probe to c2:9f:db:8d:83:7f (try 1/3)
May  7 15:24:22 box kernel: [320056.211818] wlan0: direct probe to c2:9f:db:8d:83:7f (try 2/3)
May  7 15:24:22 box kernel: [320056.416081] wlan0: direct probe to c2:9f:db:8d:83:7f (try 3/3)
May  7 15:24:22 box kernel: [320056.620315] wlan0: authentication with c2:9f:db:8d:83:7f timed out`

The full output is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7410406/

How can I get more information to debug this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Same problem here. Started after a dist-upgrade in Ubuntu 15.04.